# Change property of checkbox in the datatemplate in Listview

Tags: windows, listview, windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1

I have user control which I am using as a datatemplate for a listview. The content of this template is a simple checkbox.

```XAML
<UserControl> 
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="CheckBox">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="CheckBox">
                      ......
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <CheckBox Content="{Binding CheckBoxContent}"
                  VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

The Listview is something like this

```XAML
<ListView Name="Optimization"
          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource CheckboxTemplate}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding checkboxList}"
          Width="Auto"
          FontSize="{ThemeResource TextStyleExtraLargeFontSize}"
          Margin="108,0,0,0"/>
```

My question is how do I have the font size in the content presenter inside the checkbox to take the value provided in the Listview as above.

I searched around but all the options point to WPF and none of them to windows phone or windows store apps. I also tried templatedParent on the fontsize property of contentPresenter, but it doesnt look like Listview is the parent of the template.
Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it through the ElementName binding.

When you define your UserControl - set him an x:Name

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="App1.CheckBoxUserControl"
    x:Name="CheckBoxControl"
    .............>
    ...
</UserControl>
```

Bind your FontSize of ContentPresenter to the FontSize of UserControl first of all

```
<UserControl.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="CheckBox">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="CheckBox">
                            <ContentPresenter FontSize="{Binding FontSize, ElementName=CheckBoxControl}"/>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </UserControl.Resources>
```

Then just simply bind the UserControl's FontSize to the FontSize of ListView.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="CheckboxTemplate">
            <local:CheckBoxUserControl FontSize="{Binding FontSize, ElementName=Optimization}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: No luck :(
When I try to set the ContentPresenter Fontsize to Usercontrol, ElementName intellisense does not show UsercontrolName in the option. I bypassed this but there was an error
Also what is this Optimization?

Comment: Try to put DataTemplate inside the resources of the page where ListView is defined.

Comment: Nope. Doesn't work.
I am not able to Link my ContentPresenter Fontsize with my usercontrol font size. 
What is this optimization?

Comment: Optimization - This is name of YOUR ListView control from your question! Okay, i'll update my answer.